# VB.NET find all property with custon mark

Tags: vb.net, reflection

There is any way to create a custon mark on property/field and make a loop over it? something like serializer marker.
Like:

```
<Property marker for X>
Public Propetry A as Something...

<Property marker for X>
Public Propetry B as Something...

<Property marker for X>
Public Propetry C as Something...

<Property marker for X>
Public Propetry D as Something...

<Property marker for Y>
Public Propetry W as Something...

<Property marker for Y>
Public Propetry X as Something...
```

Then create a loope over especific property marker...

```
For Each MarkX as Something in Class.GetAllPropertyWithXMarker
    'todo...
next
```

--- **Thanks for repply, this is a very simple example of how i use it. Of course this is only a example, but is perfect for me.** --

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)>
Public Class FieldAtribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Skip As Boolean = False

    Public Sub New(Skip As Boolean)
        Me.Skip = Skip
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Teste1

    <FieldAtribute(True)> _
    Public A As String = "A" 'Skip

    <FieldAtribute(False)> _
    Public B As String = "B" 'Enable

    <FieldAtribute(False)> _
    Public C As String = "C" 'Enable

End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Test As New Teste1
    With Test
        .A = True
        .B = True
        .C = True
    End With

    ShowValues(Test)
    Test = DefaultValues(Test)
    ShowValues(Test)
End Sub

Private Function DefaultValues(T As Teste1) As Teste1
    For Each Info As System.Reflection.FieldInfo In T.GetType.GetFields
        Dim CustonData As FieldAtribute = Info.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(FieldAtribute), False)(0)
        If (Not CustonData.Skip) Then
            CallByName(T, Info.Name, CallType.Set, {False})
        End If
    Next

    Return T
End Function

Private Sub ShowValues(T As Teste1)
    Console.WriteLine(T.A)
    Console.WriteLine(T.B)
    Console.WriteLine(T.C)
End Sub
```

The out put:

```
True
True
True

True <-- Target skiped by custon marker.
False
False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom attribute and mark the relevant properties with it. By using reflection, you can get the properties of a type, filter the ones that are marked with the attribute and process them.
See the following docs:

- [writing custom attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [retrieving information stored in custom attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [getting properties of a type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I gave you +1 because the links are very helpful, but this answer would be much better if it also included an example.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Thanks for the upvote. I understand your point, but was in a hurry, so I had to decide whether to just provide some code or the links. The links contain lots of samples and I encourage reading the documentation to really understand the topic - that's why I decided this way.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they are very helpful like Stevan saied.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Class PropertyMarker
    Inherits System.Attribute
End Class

Public Class Class1
    <PropertyMarker()> _
    Public ReadOnly Property A() As String
        Get
            Return "A"
        End Get
    End Property

    <PropertyMarker()> _
    Public ReadOnly Property B() As String
        Get
            Return "B"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property C() As String
        Get
            Return "C"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Sub Main()
    For Each p In (From pp In GetType(Class1).GetProperties() Where pp.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(PropertyMarker), False).Any Select pp)
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```